# Evaluating a complex integral on a straight line contour.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I was asked to evaluate this integral where C is a straight line contour of $y=x$:
$$\int_C\frac{1}{z^2+2i}dz$$

I keep getting stuck as the question did not provide any limits.

Is there any way of solving this or am I right in thinking that the question didn't provide me with enough information?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the contour is the ***entire*** straight line. That is, you would want to parameterize as 
\begin{equation}
z = t + i t, \ \ \ \ \ \ t \in (-\infty,\infty)
\end{equation}
from here we can write 
\begin{equation}
dz = (1 + i) dt, \ z^2 = 2 i t^2
\end{equation}
and the contour integral becomes
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1+i) dt}{2i (t^2 + 1)} = \frac{1}{2}(1-i) \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ dt}{t^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-i)
\end{equation}

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that 1/(t^2+1) integrates into an inverse tangent function!  Thank you!